# css 100% minus pixels not working in jquery and Chrome devtools

Tags: jquery, css

css 100% minus pixels not working in jquery and  Chrome devtools,

The following not working:

```
$(".mydiv").css({height: "calc(100%-50px)"});
```

It did not work either in Chrome devtools. Using 100% for responsive to window resize.

But it works in css style sheet:

```
.mydiv {
    height: calc(100%-50px);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces are required when using `+` (addition) or `-` (subtraction) with `calc()`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

> The `+` and `-` operators must be surrounded by [whitespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Whitespace). For instance, `calc(50% -8px)` will be parsed as a percentage followed by a negative length — an invalid expression — while `calc(50% - 8px)` is a percentage followed by a subtraction operator and a length. Likewise, `calc(8px + -50%)` is treated as a length followed by an addition operator and a negative percentage.

Your code:

```css
body>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
div>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100%-50px);
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div><div></div></div>
```

Corrected code:

```css
body>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
div>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div><div></div></div>
```